# Navigating to Sublinks hides other parent links in SharePoint Classic

Tags: navigation, term-store, term-set

I am creating an Enterprise Wiki for our company and would like the left navigation bar to always show all of the links.
I have several categories listed in the left navigation bar. I am using Managed navigation with term sets to define the categories.

The left navigation bar on the home page appears like this:

[image]

However, when navigating to any of the sublinks, it hides all of the other categories.

[image]

The top bar shows all of the links, but not the side bar. Is there a way to change this? I attempted changing the .master files but it didn't work. No change at all was apparent.

These are not subsites, just pages that are nested.
I'm not sure it helps, but the URL to the page is:
/sites/SunshineWiki/smartsheet/sheets